# After upgrading Blender my scene renders differently

Tags: rendering

After upgrading from Blender 3.5 to 3.6, one of my scenes doesn't render properly. I've spent almost 3 hours doing a side by side comparison of every setting I can think of that might be causing this. When I upgraded I copied all my 3.5 setting across. I've attached renders from 3.5 and 3.6. Looks like something really simple but I'm going crazy trying to find what's causing it. Light Paths > Max Bounces are all the same. Any suggestions?

Blender 3.5 Render
[image: Blender 3.5]

Blender 3.6 Render
[image]

Blender 3.5 Nodes for green powder
[image]

Blender 3.6 Nodes for green powder
[image]

Comment: Indirect lighting values might be clamped

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Setting is the same (10.0) for 3.5 and 3.6.

Comment: Can you [edit] to add a screenshot of the material nodes for the ground up powder?  I'm sure it's a portion of the difference

Comment: It also might be worth looking at subsurface scattering values on everything green across the scene.

Comment: Thanks Allen, I've added the screenshots as you suggested but I don't think it can be an issue with the material settings because it's the same file, so surely the material settings will be identical?

Comment: It's as if one light is missing from the 3.6 version (notice the wicker basket is also darker) but I've checked all the lights, including the HDRI and don't see any difference. I'm so confused !? :-)

Comment: I turned off the Scene Lights and Scene World and there is still a very visible difference between them. Elements of the 3.6 version are darker, especially the small collection of powder capsules.

Comment: Hehe this is why you don't upgrade Blender mid-project and why some people are still using V2.79 :) Definitely something fishy with the normal maps as Allen pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm gonna say that something changed with how Normal Maps are handled.  To me it looks like your Normal Map Strengths are too high.

That value of 1.1 actually means 1.1 meters, so that's going to make them take on the appearance of something *unnaturally* textured, and that causes the shadows to be darker.  In *Tangent Space* this might actually make the surfaces appear as though they've been turned away from your light sources a bit.

The biggest clues to me are the dark shadows on the green powder and the details on the bowl, but as you say it looks like the wicker basket and blanket in the back are just slightly darker as well.

[image][image]

I betcha if you lower the strength down to .1 (or even lower) this effect starts to disappear.  Not clear why there is this difference between versions.

I suppose the only other place I can think to look is the material settings pane, I think it's changed some recently.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again Allen - that makes a lot of sense but unfortunately adjusting the normal map strength doesn't seem to make any difference. I only tried it very quickly though so I'll spend more time with it later and get back to you. Thanks again.

Comment: It's all dependent on scene scale as well, so potentially you'll have to decrease that to a very small value

Comment: Thanks again for all your suggestions Allen. I just can't seem to get it to work. I'll come back to it at a later date if I have time. Sorry for the newbie question but how do I give you kudos, or ratings or thanks on Stack Exchange?

Comment: Don't worry too much about it Marcus, happy to help.  You can always run those two versions side by side if you're careful about where you open your projects.